# why does string format statement in python 2.x doesn't produce error when int or float value is given in substitution for string

Tags: python-2.7, string-formatting

when non string value is give in substitution for string place holder it doesn't produce error while it does when given non int or float value.

```
>>> 'In %d years I have spotted %g %s.' % (3.1, 0, 123456)
'In 3 years I have spotted 0 123456.'
>>> 'In %d years I have spotted %g %s.' % ('3.1', 0, '123')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
>>> 'In %d years I have spotted %g %s.' % (3.1, "0", '123')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: float argument required, not str
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

```
's'     String (converts any Python object using str()).
```

`str()` converts objects by calling their `__str__` method. This is how it works for `int`: `int` has implemented `__str__` method which converts it to a string.

If an object has no `__str__` method implemented, its `__repr__` method is called. All objects in Python inherit default implementation of this method, which returns object class name and memory address. So this means that you can pass pretty much every object to `%s` and this will not produce an error, but print some kind of its string representation.